# In typescript, how can I make sure a function doesn't return anything

Tags: typescript

In typescript, how do I type a function so it cannot have a return value?
`() => void` on first glance looks like it might work:

```ts
type A = () => void
const a1: A = () => {}
const a2: A = () => 5     // No error
```

The issue here is that `a2` must error.
How can this be written so that `a1` is successful, but `a2` fails with a transpilation-time error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type that would work for `a1` and cause `a2` to error is `() => undefined`.

See the following:

```ts
type A = () => undefined
const a1: A = () => {}
const a2: A = () => 5     // Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```